# Get current seeder's IP addresses of a torrent using PHP

Tags: php, p2p, bittorrent

I am working on a BitTorrent like thing.  How can I show the current seeder's IP address and their country flag the way it is shown in BitTorrent client?

Comment: Wait, why would bill gates give a flying eff?

Comment: ah Nothin :) ... i am able to get the total number of seeders and leechers , and tracker lists

Comment: Are you working on a BitTorrent client, or something of your own devising?

Comment: @andrewsi .. Something of my own ... please help guys

Comment: Well, something like http://www.maxmind.com/app/locate_demo_ip will let you lookup country based on IP addresses - they offer an API, I believe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two largely separate parts - querying the torrent tracker for the seeders IP, and reverse-geocoding the IP addresses to determine the country.

The reverse-geocoding part is a common thing, and easily done. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033/ip-to-country) lists several options, and [this one is similar, but specifically for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650006/get-country-of-ip-address-with-php)

The torrent-tracker-querying part is a bit more complicated, due to the various types of torrent trackers. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140300/sending-scrape-request-for-getting-torrents-seeds-and-peers) explains what you need to do

Comment: Hi thAnks @dbr ... can u provide a example ? a working script